# Display a list in a partial view at post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this code in my controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(double userLat, double userLng)
    {
        var context = new weddingspreeEntities();
        var coordinates = context.Venues
            .Select(loc => new { vname = loc.VenueName, lat = loc.VenueLat, lng = loc.VenueLong })
            .ToList();

                    string venueName = string.Empty;
        List<SearchModel.DistLocation> venDistList = new List<SearchModel.DistLocation>();

        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Count; i++)
        {
            string name = coordinates[i].vname;
            double? lat = coordinates[i].lat;
            double? lng = coordinates[i].lng;





            var loc1Lat = lat.Value;
            var loc1Lng = lng.Value;
            var loc2Lat = userLat;
            var loc2Lng = userLng;




            double distance = TrackingHelper.CalculateDistance(
                new SearchModel.Location() { Latitude = loc1Lat, Longitude = loc1Lng },
                new SearchModel.Location() { Latitude = loc2Lat, Longitude = loc2Lng });

            //convert kilometers to miles
            double distMiles = distance * 0.621371192;

            venueName = name;




            venDistList.Add(new SearchModel.DistLocation() { venName = name, Distance = distMiles });
        }




        return View(venDistList);
    }
```

I have this code in my view:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cityName)*@
                <label>Enter City and State or Zip Code</label>
                <input type="text" id="citystate" name="citystate" />
                <label>Enter Your Wedding Date</label>
                <input class="datefield" data-val="true" data-val-required="Date is required" id="weddingDate" name="weddingDate" type="date" value="1/11/1989" />
                <label>Enter Your Guest Count</label>
                <input type="text" id="guestcount" name="guestcount" />
                <input type="button" id="search" name="search" value="Search for Venues" />
            }
        </div>

        <!--This is the div where the google map will render -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 600px;"></div>
        </div>

    </div>  

</div>

    <div>
        @Html.Partial("_SearchResults")
    </div>
```

I have omitted some of my view for brevity

This is the partial view I am trying to render:

```
    @model IEnumerable<WeddingSpree_Alpha.Models.SearchModel.DistLocation>

@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @item.venName
        @item.Distance
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to have the user enter the values in the search box and then after the click post the results (in the list named venDistList) to the view using a foreach statement.

The model looks like this:

```
    public class SearchModel
{
    public string cityName { get; set; }
    public DateTime weddingDate { get; set; }
    public int guestCount { get; set; }


    public class Location
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }

    public class DistLocation
    {
        public string venName { get; set; }
        public double Distance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like the list results to populate after the button click (post) on the page.  I thought my code would do that however.  I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

I know that error happens when you try to use a model that is not populated yet but I thought I did that in my controller code?  What exactly could be throwing that error?

This is the controller code for my partial view:

```
        public ActionResult _SearchResults(SearchModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing: `return View(venDistList);` to return `PartialView("_SearchResults", venDistList)`?

Comment: @Thierry I get the same error when I make that change

Comment: Please add more stacktrace info when trying to seek help for an exception with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not at least instantiating an instance of IEnumerable to pass back (even if it is empty) then it will throw the null reference when you try to iterate throught the model in the partial view.

Edit: (Code trimmed down for example) Your original error is that you are trying to iterate through an object that does not exist. The below will show you how to make user of an Ajax call on your form submit to dynamically generate your partial view and attach it to your main page

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _SearchResults(string citystate, DateTime? weddingDate, double? guestcount)
    {
        List<SearchModel.DistLocation> venDistList = new List<SearchModel.DistLocation>();
        venDistList.Add(new SearchModel.DistLocation() { venName = "weee1", Distance = 2 });
        venDistList.Add(new SearchModel.DistLocation() { venName = "weee2", Distance = 4 });
        venDistList.Add(new SearchModel.DistLocation() { venName = "weee3", Distance = 6 });

        return PartialView(venDistList);
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

    @*This is our form which will feed our user input and drive our search results output*@
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form id="searchMe">
                    <label>Enter City and State or Zip Code</label>
                    <input type="text" id="citystate" name="citystate" />
                    <label>Enter Your Wedding Date</label>
                    <input class="datefield" data-val="true" data-val-required="Date is required" id="weddingDate" name="weddingDate" type="date" value="1/11/1989" />
                    <label>Enter Your Guest Count</label>
                    <input type="text" id="guestcount" name="guestcount" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search for Venues</button>
                </form>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @*This is where we want our search results to appear when user hits submit on our form*@
        <div id="SearchResult"></div>
    </div>




    @section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //When the user hit the submit button we will post the form results to our partial view controller
            $('#searchMe').submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/_SearchResults",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        //When then load our partial view into our containing div on the main page
                        $('#SearchResult').html(result);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

Partial View (_SearchResult.cshtml)

```
    @model IEnumerable<deletemeweb2.Models.SearchModel.DistLocation>

    @{
        Layout = null;
    }


    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Search Results</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @if (Model != null || Model.Count() < 1)
            {
                using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <p>@item.venName</p>
                        <p>@item.Distance</p>
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
               <p>No results found</p>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I added the partial view controller

Comment: and there is your problem. Your partial view is expecting you to pass back IEnumerable<WeddingSpree_Alpha.Models.SearchModel.DistLocation> but you are not passing back anything

Comment: I see so should it read more like [code]public ActionResult _SearchResults(SearchModel.DistLocation model)[/code]

Comment: Your form post should be sending to your partial controller. The logic you have in your Index (httppost) controller should be in your partial controller and it should pass back the IEnumerble to your partial view. Hopefully that makes sense but if not then I can mod my answer for a better example

Comment: Ok I just re-read the answer sorry - so I should put everything from the post index controller into the _SearchResults controller and then pass it to the index controller via "return partialview(_SearchResults)" Correct? That would be great if you have the time to modify the answer

Comment: No, your form post (razor_ should be posting to your partial view controller. All logic to generate the IEnumerable<object> shoudl take place in that partial controller and it should pass it back directly to your partial view. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you Travis I think I am to dense to understand words sometimes :-)

Comment: Ok I did as you said and my partial view is still not rendering.

Comment: The default given works perfectly fine as it came directly from VS for you. If you have github or would like to share your solution so I can see specifically what is going on with your implementation then I'd be happy to as time allows.